# why is there no need to execute function using () when it is declared by arrow function?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Hi arrow function question again :(

Here is part of my codes.

[image]

As you can see, initial**** s are function. right??
and dateRangeArr is also function

Here is the question.

[image]

I called dateRageArr() to use.

[image]

but initial blahs like initialPage, initialRowsPerPage 
I dont need to use ()

I wonder why...

thanks a lot in advance :)

Comment: I read your question a couple of times and I couldn't understand what you asking, you may want to try and rephrase it a bit.

Answer (score 1):

This is because `useState` will call the function immediately, if a function is passed as the argument. Whereas normally, you need to use `()` to invoke a function.

To demonstrate, below I pass a function to `useState` instead of an actual value.

```
const MyTest  = () => {
  const func = () => {
    return 'my func result';
  }

  [val, setVal] = React.useState(func);
  //                                 ^ no ()

  return 'initial state: ' + val;
};
```

Result:

> initial state: my func result

As you can see, this produces the same result as doing:

```
[val, setVal] = React.useState(func());
//                                 ^^ explicitly call it
```

It's simply a helper feature that you can pass a function without explicitly calling it.